# Checking if a number is palindrome or not in Java

Tags: java, interview-questions, palindrome

Got this question in a technical interview and here is my solution:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (!in.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("not a number!");
    }

    int number = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println(isPalidrom(number));
  }

  private static String isPalidrom(int number) {

    String numberStr = Integer.toString(number);
    String reverseStr = new StringBuilder(numberStr).reverse().toString();

    if (reverseStr.equals(numberStr)) {
      return "palindrome";
    } else {
      return "not palindrome";
    }
  }
}
```

I was going to solve it with using modulus 10 and decided to do it by reverting the number to integer, was it a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips:

- `Main` is a confusing class name. In your case, an appropriate name might possibly be `PalindromeChecker`.
- Your `main` method would usually be in a separate class called for example `Application`. That way

  1. `PalindromeChecker` ends up with a public method for doing the actual check, making the class reusable and
  2. the library and executable parts of your program are properly separated.
- Why scan for numbers? You are reading from standard input, which by definition is just a byte stream, so you might as well avoid some conversion and just check whether each line that arrives is a palindrome. Number checking could be done elsewhere, if absolutely necessary.
- The checker function should return a boolean, to avoid mixing logic and presentation. The function also becomes objectively simpler: `return reverseStr.equals(numberStr);`
- Look into other ways of [converting a string to an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4105331/96588) - they have different pros and cons.
- Writing up some test methods could expose unexpected behaviour. For example, what does your code do with alternative numbering systems such as Roman or Chinese numerals? Does it handle `10.1` as one integer (101 or 10), two integers (10 and 1), or does it reject it? Does it expand numbers such as `1e5`? Does it precompute arithmetic such as `10+1`? Converting the `int` back to a `String` and comparing it with the original `String` input might be a useful way of telling whether any automagic conversion has occurred.
- I believe [tell, don't ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) applies to the way `in` is used.

That said, your solution is simple and quick. Given the time & stress of an interview I'd say you nailed it. (Provided it works - I haven't actually run it :)